# How do I delete an html element from a file I sent to beautifulSoup class?

Tags: python, methods, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python/beautifulSoup to find a div of a specific class, and I want to nuke that entire html element from a file.

This is what I have --

```
with open(url) as f:
  elementToDelete = BeautifulSoup(f.read()).find("div", {'class': 'element-that-needs-to-go'})
  removeTheElement = elementToDelete.replace('THISISWHEREIMSTUCK', '')
with open(url, 'w') as f:
  f.write(removeTheElement)
```

I can't seem to find the right method to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the decompose method :

**Python Code :**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div>
  <div class="element-that-needs-to-go">
  </div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tag_to_remove = soup.find("div", {'class': 'element-that-needs-to-go'})
tag_to_remove.decompose()
print(soup)
```

**Demo :** [Here](https://repl.it/repls/ImmenseMobileExperiment)

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot.  But when I try to write 'soup' in the file again:

'''
with open(url, 'w') as f:  
f.write(removeTheElement)
'''
I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import.py", line 97, in <module>
    header.write(removeFundLink)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: oh my god, you are my hero. thank you! its almost 4am now i can sleep.